# createProcess() not working?

Tags: c++, createprocess

I am trying to open a program using visual c++ on windows visual studio 2012 professional on windows 7.The code will run smoothly but will not actually open the program. I'm also not getting any build errors at all. Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main ()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
    if (!
    CreateProcess
            (
            TEXT("C:\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"),
            NULL,NULL,NULL,FALSE,
            CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
            NULL,NULL,
            &si,
            &pi
            )
            )
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to execute.";
        }

}
```

I am trying to open google chrome as a test try. Also, I got partly this code and some help from this website http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/48283/ I'll appreciate any help at all!

edit:

now that I know that the createProcess function is working. How come if I try to open text files with c++, there will be no errors, but the actual text notepad won't open up. Here's the code

```
STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
    if (!
    CreateProcess
            (
            TEXT("C:\\Users\\Mohammed Mehdi\\Documents\\Test\\Test.txt"),
            NULL,NULL,NULL,FALSE,
            CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
            NULL,NULL,
            &si,
            &pi
            )
            )
        {
            cout << "Unable to execute.";
        }
```

Comment: Try escaping the first `\\ :  `"C:\\Progr...`

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm not able to add proper code tags to my comment... For test, in this one I will put a single backslash enclosed by 2 graves: `\`

Comment: Yeah you were right, thanks for the answer. Didn't think double backslashes mattered because it didn't give an error

Comment: Regarding the new question about opening a .txt file: You probably want to use [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx), with `TEXT("open")` for the operation argument.  This gives the same result as double-clicking the file in explorer -- .exe files are executed, .txt files are opened in your editor, and other types are handled as you would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are missing a '\'.

Instead of 
`TEXT("C:\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe")`

Try
`TEXT("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe")`

Comment: Thank you for that. Can't believe I missed that out. At first I thought you only had to have double backslashes in only some places because usually you wouldn't get an error for it. Got to remember that for next time!

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of the question, you're trying to use your own txt as a process. That does not work. Instead, use notepad:

```
TEXT("C:\\Users\\Mohammed Mehdi\\Documents\\Test\\Test.txt")
```

To:

```
TEXT("C:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe /A C:\\Users\\Mohammed Mehdi\\Documents\\Test\\Test.txt")
```